# SlickJS not working only html viewed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a slideshow using [SlickJS](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

I have followed the guidelines to create this slideshow however instead of getting the actual slideshow I get a bunch of HTML instead. Here is my work:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="your-class">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.your-class').slick({
        arrows: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are loading the default styles with...

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" />`

If you remove this line you can see the buttons and elements slide appropriately. You can then style the elements with your own css more easily like creating your own custom buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it has something to do with your imports. I've tried using the latest version of `jQuery` and `slickjs` and that seems to work locally. See the code below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="your-class">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.your-class').slick({
        arrows: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, Do you have an idea of how I can add buttons and change the numbers to images?